# Is there a program to capture Screenshots and upload to FTP

Tags: windows-7, ftp, screenshot

I am in search of a program that will let me capture screenshots and FTP them to a web server.  It could also be a Google Chrome plugin, I have 2 plugins now that both allow me to snap screenshots (if in the browser window) and either save them to my PC, upload to diigo.com, or my facebook.

The plugins are called **Explain and Send Screenshots** and **Awesome screenshot**

The only thing lacking is the ability to upload to FTP.

I would really like to find a lightweight program that will sit in the windows taskbar tray and allow me to easily take screenshots and automaticly upload them to an FTP server.

If you know of a program that can do that, please share?

Comment: I don't know of any specifically, maybe someone will, but is there any reason you can't set a script to monitor a folder that the screen shots will go into and upload them as they get saved to that folder?

Comment: It would be helpful if you stated your preferred OS.

Comment: @Nifle good oint, Windows 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ZScreen](http://code.google.com/p/zscreen/)! It's free and can upload files to FTP, file hosting services and many other options.

The screenshot below was created and hosted with one click.

[image]

Comment: I found this a few weeks ago, it is simply amazing

Comment: Just been to Zscreen site and it has migrated into http://getsharex.com/ .Very usefull. Thank for finding it out!

Answer (score 0):

[**HyperSnap**](http://www.hyperionics.com/hsdx/) can be automated to upload to an FTP server.  It's not free, but you may find it worth buying, for whatever you are doing.

I used it around ten years ago, when it was called HyperSnap-DX.  It can take screenshots of entire webpages, even when they scroll down further than the screen size, which can be pretty useful.

[image: HyperSnap]